# strange result from strtok

Tags: c, token

I am attempting to split up a string into tokens and store them in an array.

```
printf("crack_lines[0] : %s\n",crack_lines[0]);
i = 0;
char *encrypted[crack_word_count];
encrypted[i] = strtok(crack_lines[0]," ");
while(encrypted[i] != NULL)
{
    printf("%s\n",encrypted[i]);
    i++;
    encrypted[i] = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

but when I run it the output is :

```
crack_lines[0] : NY'X YNRJ YT UQFD YMJ RZXNH


1


w
n
```

I'm really not sure why it is printing this and I'm wondering if anybody has any ideas on why. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Don't you own a debugger?

Comment: What is `crack_word_count`? What is `crack_lines`? Does `crack_lines[0]` point to a string constant? (The meaning of the code you've shown us depends on code we can't see.)

Comment: Post a complete, compilable example program.  That way we won't have to guess about things like the type of `crack_lines` or what `crack_word_count` is.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation of strtok](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok):

> This function is destructive: it writes the '\0' characters in the
>   elements of the string str. In particular, a string literal cannot be
>   used as the first argument of strtok.

This works for me:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char* crack_line = malloc(128);
    strcpy(crack_line, "NY'X YNRJ YT UQFD YMJ RZXNH");
    const int crack_word_count = 32;
    printf("crack_lines : %s\n", crack_line);
    int i = 0;
    char *encrypted[crack_word_count];
    encrypted[i] = strtok(crack_line," ");
    while(encrypted[i] != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n",encrypted[i]);
        i++;
        encrypted[i] = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: You may be right. Hard to say since the OP's gone silent. But I'm having trouble understanding how this issue is producing the results he reported.

Comment: I get a segfault with `char* crack_line = "NY'X YNRJ YT UQFD YMJ RZXNH"`. But I am only guessing this might be the issue...